# Please what's wrong with this code, it's my homework I keep getting error

Tags: javascript

The above exercise was created to be completed by my teacher and I keep getting error when I ran it.

```
function exerciseOne() {
    // Exercise One: In this exercise you will create a variable called 'aboutMe'
    // This variable should be assigned a new object
    // In this object create three key:value pairs
    // The keys should be: 'name', 'city', 'favoriteAnimal'
    // The values should be strings associated with the keys.
    // return the variable 'aboutMe'

    let aboutMe = {
        name: 'Adebola Adesina',
        city: 'Los Angeles',
        favoriteAnimal: 'Zebra'
    };
    return aboutMe;
}

function exerciseTwo(animal) {
    // Exercise Two: In this exercise you will be given an object called 'animal'
    // Create a new variable called 'animalName'
    // Accessing the animal object, assign the 'animalName' variable to the 'latinName' key on the object.
    // return the animalName variable.

    animalName = animal.latinName;
}
return animalName;

function exerciseThree(userObject) {
    // Exercise Three: In this exercise you will be given an object called 'userObject'
    // The phonne number for this user is incorrect!
    // reassign the 'phoneNumber' key to the value: '(951)867-5309'
    // return the userObject

    userObject.phoneNumber = '(951)867-5309';
}
return userObject;
```

The above exercise was created to be completed by my teacher and I keep getting error when I ran it.

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: Your return statements are outside of the function blocks for execiseTwo and exerciseThree

Comment: `return animalName;` should be before `}` not after it. Same goes for `return userObject;`

Comment: The code doesn't implement the instructions of exerciseTwo at all

Comment: Thank you all. I'm new to JS and Caius what you mean the code doesn't implement the instructions of exercise Two, I thought the error is from returning outside the function scope and not the code implementation?

Answer (score 0):

```
function exerciseTwo(animal) {
    animalName = animal.latinName;
    return animalName;
}
function exerciseThree(userObject) {
    userObject.phoneNumber = '(951)867-5309';
    return userObject;
}
```

You have to return the variables inside the function. Read about scope in javascript and differences between var and let. Also, read the error carefully and debug in browser using breakpoints and you will understand where the code is breaking.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to JS I know let is Constant and about debugging and breakpoint I'm running the code on real.it I'm not running running it from the  browser console the error message is a lot Lol can't even round my he round it but I will give it a  try.

Comment: did this solve your error though? If yes, you can pick the answer as accepted answer. And for error messages, there will usually be a hyperlink with an underline and if you click that, you will be able to trace the error back to the source.